# Using WPAlchemy metabox values in another metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, php, admin, metabox, post-editor

I'm building a quite complex custom post type structure and I would need some help regarding my metaboxes.

What I want to do:

1. Thank's to the `have_fields_and_multi()` function, the user enters data in simple text input fields (with a "Add new" button)
2. The values from the previous text inputs should be used to build a `select` dropdown in another metabox.

To make it simple, here is a mockup (also attached to this post): http://idzr.org/0c95

I have the first part working, it's easy. But I can't figure out how to make the second part to work. If I use a `while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('aaa'))` in another `while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('bbb'))` the page is infinite (the loop doesn't end. If I use `foreach` I have other problems.

Do you have an idea about how I can achieve this ? Thanks!!!

Comment: The link doesn't work. You can also upload images here directly.

Comment: @kaiser I edited the link. (I can't post captures as it was my first post in **this** StackExchange website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to solve that by myself. It is possible thanks to :

1. Create the first field :

   ```
   <?php
       while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('types')):
       $mb->the_group_open();
       $mb->the_field('type');
   ?>
   <input type="text" id="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>" />
   <a href="#" class="dodelete button">Remove</a>
   <?php
       $mb->the_group_close();
       endwhile;
   ?>
   <a href="#" class="docopy-types button" style="float: left">Add new</a>
   <a href="#" class="dodelete-types button" style="float: right">Delete all</a>
   ```
2. Create the second batch of fields while using `foreach` to get the data from the first fields and put that in a `select` :

   ```
   <?php
       while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('details')):
       $mb->the_group_open();
       $mb->the_field('detail_select');
   ?>
   <select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
       <option value="">Choose...</option>
       <?php foreach ($meta['types'] as $types) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $types['type']; ?>"<?php $mb->the_select_state($types['type']); ?>><?php echo $types['type']; ?></option>
       <?php } ?>
   </select>
   <?php $mb->the_field('detail_title'); ?>
   <label>Description</label>
   <input type="text" id="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>" /><br />
   <a href="#" class="dodelete button">Remove</a>
   <?php
       $mb->the_group_close();
       endwhile;
   ?>
   <a href="#" class="docopy-estate_details button">Add new</a>
   <a href="#" class="dodelete-estate_details button">Delete all</a>
   ```